# Work with function calcOpticalFlowPyrLK

Tags: java, android, opencv

Can we use «MatOfPoint2f prevPts» an array of all the points MatOfPoint2f[] in method Video.calcOpticalFlowPyrLK as an input parameter, like in OpenCV for Windows?

For Android I only can do the following:

```
Video.calcOpticalFlowPyrLK(Cadr_Prev,Cadr_Current,
 Point_PrevPts[iindex],
 Point_CurrentPts[iindex],
 _bstatus[iindex], 
 _trackError[iindex]);
```

P.S. I run in cycle the function calcOpticalFlowPyrLK for each point and it affects on productivity.

Answer (score 0):

Answer from OpenCv Developer:
I am create MatOfPoint2f from Point[] array via MatOfPoint2f::fromArray() method.